# LEFT / RIGHT Joins on node-orm2

Tags: mysql, node.js, join, node-orm2

I'm using dresende/node-orm2 ORM in my node devs. But I need to make some LEFT / RIGHT joins, but i can't find how to in the docs. I'm having problems too while trying to make multiple joins.

This code :

```
crModel.hasOne ('client', cliModel, {

    field:  'client_id'
});

crModel.hasOne ('office', boModel, {

    field:  'bo_id'
});

crModel.findByClient ({}).findByOffice ({}).find ({

    client_id:  1,
    bo_id:      1
}, function () {

    console.log (arguments);
});
```

generates this query:

```
SELECT `t1`.`cr_id`, `t1`.`cr_datetime`, `t1`.`credit_id`, `t1`.`gs_id`, `t1`.`cellphone_id`, `t1`.`bo_id`, `t1`.`client_id` FROM `CreditRequests` `t1` JOIN `BranchOffices` `t2` ON `t2`.`bo_id` = `t1`.`bo_id` WHERE `t1`.`client_id` = 1 AND `t1`.`bo_id` = 1
```

Thanks, and sorry about my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

The trick with ORM is to envision the relationship, not the command to make it work.  With ORM2 there is a hasMany association - I would start there. from the docs:

```
patient.getDoctors(function..)           // List of doctors
patient.addDoctors(docs, function...)    // Adds entries to join table
patient.setDoctors(docs, function...)    // Removes existing entries in join table, adds new ones
patient.hasDoctors(docs, function...)    // Checks if patient is associated to specified doctors
patient.removeDoctors(docs, function...) // Removes specified doctors from join table

doctor.getPatients(function..)
etc...

// You can also do:
patient.doctors = [doc1, doc2];
patient.save(...)
```

https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2